# determinant recursive formula of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For a field $K, n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $\lambda \in K$ let $A_{n, \lambda} \in \textrm{Mat} (n,K) $ be the following matrix with entries $\lambda$ on the diagonal, $-1$ on both minor diagonals and $0$ elsewhere.

$A_{n, \lambda}=\begin {pmatrix} \lambda & -1\\ -1 & \lambda & -1\\  & -1 & \lambda & -1\\ & & \ddots& \ddots &\ddots \\ & & & &  -1 \\  & & & -1  & \lambda &   \end{pmatrix}$

I trying to deduce a recursion formula for $d_{n,\lambda}:=\det (A_{n,\lambda})$ i.e. i want to constitute for $n > 1 $ the number $d_{n,\lambda}$ through numbers $d_{k,\lambda}$ with $0<k<n$.

Furthermore i want to show, that for all $ k \in \mathbb{N}$

$d_{2+3k,1}=0$

My idea was to calculate a few values and then conclude using mathematical induction, but my problem is to find the correct pattern... The values a calculated are $d_{2,\lambda} = \lambda ^2-1, d_{3,\lambda}= \lambda(\lambda^2-1), d_{4,\lambda}= \lambda^4-3\lambda^2+1$

Comment: Every term in the expansion either uses the $\lambda$ in the upper left corner, or use both the $-1$s in the upper left corner. That should enable you to write a recursion.

Comment: See the words of wisdom in [this wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant)

Comment: It's a Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix, with well-studied properties (in particular, the recursion you seek is related to the recursion for the Chebyshev polynomials.)

Answer (score 1):

Expand with respect to the first column we get
$$
d_n = \lambda d_{n-1} - d_{n-2}
$$
which must be complemented with
$$d_0=1, \quad d_1 =\lambda
$$

Now
$$
d_{n+3}
= \lambda d_{n+2} - d_{n+1}
= \lambda (\lambda d_{n+1} - d_{n}) - d_{n+1}
= (\lambda^2-1) d_{n+1} - \lambda d_{n}
$$
and so, considering $d_n$ as a polynomial in $\lambda$, we have by induction that $d_{2+3k}$ is a multiple of $\lambda^2-1$ because $d_2 = \lambda^2-1$.

In particular, $d_{2+3k}(\pm 1)=0$.